# Need to sum up the values in one cell which are separated by "addition" sign in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here in the picture I need to sum up the values in cell D4, D5 which are separated by "add" sign and brackets. I already have the formula which calculates that, but it doesn't sum when there is no space between the number and brackets. How can I moderate this formula in order to calculate that both with space and without? Here is the formula which  calculates that for cell D5

```
=if (D5>0, SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(D5, "[^\d\.()]+", "|"), "|")), " ")
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you can just use `"\D+"` as a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following formula:

`=IF(D5 > 0, SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(D5,"\([^()]*\)", ""), "+")), "")`

The REGEX will remove anything between and including the parentheses, and the SPLIT separates the numbers by the "+" symbol.